# How To Loop Nested If-Then Statements in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I am going to try to simplify my objective as well as add all of my vba as my OP was not clear.

I am writing a macro that is to be used to determine a commissions percentage based on a particular strategies (Tier1, Tier2, BPO or Enterprise), a Gross Margin range and contract year.  This will need to be looped through about 5,000 rows of data in the final product.  I have been trying to nest multiple If-Then statements to achieve my goal however it is not working.

Below is the table for the commissions rates that apply to each of the strategies and then the code that I wrote for this nested If-Then statement.

Looking to try to make this simpler and loop it through the entirety of the rows with data. Goal is to have each cell in column J return a Commission rate determined by the strategy in column i, year in column D and GM in column Z.  The strategy has the potential to vary each row down the page. 
Would I be better off creating a custom Function?

Kinda crazy task for a first time macro writer.  Appreciate all the feedback I have gotten already and look forward to any other ideas to come.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2sm3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcERb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkAp.png)

My Code:

Where Column I = Strategy

Where Column D = Year

Where Column Z = Gross Margin

Where Column J = Result of If-Then

where Column C is a defined data set which determines the number of rows in the workbook.

Sub Define_Comm_Rate
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

```
If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "BPO" And Sheet1.Range("Z2") >= 0.24 Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.4
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.3
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.15
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "BPO" And Sheet1.Range("Z2") >= 0.21 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") < 0.24 Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.35
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.25
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.1
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "BPO" And Sheet1.Range("Z2") >= 0.18 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") < 0.21 Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.3
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.2
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.05
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "BPO" And Sheet1.Range("Z2") < 0.18 Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.25
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.15
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.05
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Enterprise24" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = "1" Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.4
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.3
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.15
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Enterprise21" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.35
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.25
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.1
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Enterprise18" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.3
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.2
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.05
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Enterprise00" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.25
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("D2") = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.15
        Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.05
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Tier1" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.4 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.4 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.25 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = (1 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) + 0.1
        Else
            If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.25 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.075 Then
                Sheet1.Range("J2") = (2 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) - 0.15
            Else
               If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.075 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0 Then
                    Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0
               Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
               End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Tier1-100" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.4 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.4 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.25 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = (1 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) + 0.1
        Else
            If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.25 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.075 Then
                Sheet1.Range("J2") = (2 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) - 0.15
            Else
               If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.075 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0 Then
                    Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0
               Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
               End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Tier2" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.35 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.35 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.25 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = (1 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) + 0.15
        Else
            If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.25 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.05 Then
                Sheet1.Range("J2") = (2 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) - 0.1
            Else
                If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.05 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0 Then
                    Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0
                Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If


If Sheet1.Range("I2") = "Tier2-100" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.35 Then
        Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
    Else
        If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.35 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.25 Then
            Sheet1.Range("J2") = (1 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) + 0.15
        Else
            If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.25 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0.05 Then
                Sheet1.Range("J2") = (2 * Sheet1.Range("Z2")) - 0.1
            Else
                If Sheet1.Range("Z2") <= 0.05 And Sheet1.Range("Z2") > 0 Then
                    Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0
                Else: Sheet1.Range("J2") = 0.5
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Sheet1.Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
Application.Calculate
```

End Sub

Comment: I don't see any loops, the code all refers to specific cells, and you don't explain what you mean by "it is not working".

Comment: Please do not put clarifications id the comments.  Instead [edit] your original post and add the clarifications to the original post.

Comment: And `option explicit`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer a non-VBA approach to this using `INDIRECT`, `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and a few tables. My thought is that instead of coding lots of nested IF's, with hard-coded values, in VBA, you should be able to do this with lookup tables. (Disclaimer: this was also a fun intellectual exercise.)

First, create a table similar to the Commissions Table you already have and name it your specific strategy, e.g. "BPO", under Formulas > Name Manager. I created mine on a separate sheet named "Tables". Note that I used 1 in row 1 as your max (*and unrealistic*) gross margin. I also added 1, 2, and 3 in cells `B1`, `C1`, and `D1` respectively. You'd need to create similar tables for your other strategies, and put them under the BPO table.

[image]

Then in column J on your data tab, enter this formula: `=INDEX(INDIRECT(I2),MATCH(Z2,INDIRECT(I2&"["&Z$1&"]"),-1),MATCH(D2,Tables!$A$1:$D$1,1))`

[image]

This INDEX formula has 3 main parts:

1. `INDIRECT(I2)` - this returns the array comprising the table you have named "BPO" - so you know you're looking at the table appropriate to that particular strategy.
2. `MATCH(Z2,INDIRECT(I2&"["&Z$1&"]"),-1)` - this looks up your gross margin in column Z against the table (BPO), looking in the column[Gross Margin]. The last argument of MATCH (match type) is -1, meaning that it finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to your gross margin (note that in the table, Gross Margin is sorted in descending order). So for example, if your Gross Margin is 0.22, the MATCH will return 0.2399.
3. `MATCH(D2,Tables!$A$1:$D$1,1)` - This looks up the year, and tries to find the largest value that is less than or equal to it. So if the year is 1, 2, or 3, the MATCH will return 1, 2, or 3, respectively, but if the year is greater than 3, the MATCH returns 3.

Columns AB and AC in the second screenshot are just the results of *2.* and *3.* above, included to show that the correct commission value is being returned. Note that the *"Year Column"* is not Year 2 or Year 3, but the 2nd or 3rd column in the BPO table, i.e. Year 1 or Year 2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback BigBen.  I originally had this file build as Index Matches and IfStatement formulas that were dragged down for all cells.  The problem is that with all the other formulas in the workbook, even dragging down the formulas took 10 minutes for the workbook to update.  Again talking about 5,000 rows of data referencing 4 underlying data tabs.

I will certainly give your ideas a try!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input/feedback.

Due to added complexity of additional sales plans needing to be incorporated as well as needing the flexibility to add/remove sales plans at any time, I ended up writing a custom Function.

```
Function Commissions(Strategy As String, GM As Variant, YR As Variant) As Variant


If Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.24 And YR = 1 Then
    Commissions = 0.4
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.24 And YR = 2 Then
    Commissions = 0.3
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.24 And YR >= 3 Then
    Commissions = 0.15
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.21 And GM < 0.24 And YR = 1 Then
    Commissions = 0.35
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.21 And GM < 0.24 And YR = 2 Then
    Commissions = 0.25
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.21 And GM < 0.24 And YR >= 3 Then
    Commissions = 0.1
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.18 And GM < 0.21 And YR = 1 Then
    Commissions = 0.3
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.18 And GM < 0.21 And YR = 2 Then
    Commissions = 0.2
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM >= 0.18 And GM < 0.21 And YR >= 3 Then
    Commissions = 0.05
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM < 0.18 And YR = 1 Then
    Commissions = 0.25
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM < 0.18 And YR = 2 Then
    Commissions = 0.15
ElseIf Strategy = "BPO" And GM < 0.18 And YR >= 3 Then
    Commissions = 0.05
''all other strategies continued below....''

End If
End Function
```

Comment: **Select Case** would probably be cleaner here rather **ElseIf**

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look into that.  I have never used Select Case before.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at this on my phone and didn’t see your other criteria off the screen. ElseIf is probably the better way to go :)